# Mac asking for password using SSH after setting up keys on both Macs

Tags: macos, ssh

I've bought a new Mac and while moving to the new one I log into my old Mac via SSH to keep using my old setup.

I've copied id_rsa and id_rsa.pub from my old mac to the new one but whenever I try to login using ssh myname@ol_dmac_ip it always asks me for a password.
Using verbose mode it looks like it is presenting the key:

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /Users/julianf/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:*REDACTED_FOR_SAFETY*
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
```

On my old mac I'm trying to look for sshd issues in /var/log/systemlog but there's nothing useful. I've also checked permissions on home directories, .ssh directories, and both sets of id_rsa and id_rsa.pub files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `sshd` to allow you to log in using a private key, the corresponding public key must be present in `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the old Mac. You can usually just do something like `cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys`, which will create the file if it doesn't already exist (which it may well not, if you haven't previously been trying to log in using ssh).

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it.  
Then I had to set up a config file so it didn't ask me for the key's passphrase every time.